# Modifying a Fortran array in C

Tags: c, arrays, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

In Fortran I have a an array specified as:

```
dimension insv(*)
```

Now I would like to edit this array from C.
I managed to read the array from C by using the iso_c_binding:

```
  SUBROUTINE userroutine(insv)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTERFACE
  SUBROUTINE MODIFYARRAY(insv) BIND(C)
  USE, INTRINSIC::ISO_C_BINDING
     REAL(C_DOUBLE),DIMENSION(*), INTENT(INOUT) :: insv
  END SUBROUTINE MODIFYARRAY
  END INTERFACE

  dimension insv(*)

  WRITE(insv(0))
  call modifyarray(insv)
  WRITE(insv(0))
  END
```

My C function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void modifyarray(double * insv)
```

But modifying a value in this array in C either crashes or simply doesnt get changed at all.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void modifyarray(double * insv)
{
    insv[0] = 1234.00;
}
```

Im not sure as to what i should change to the iso_c_binding or the C function to make this work.

Some more context: The fortran array type cannot be changed since the dimension variable is a parameter of a userroutine, not in my control, so to say.
The array is already filled when entering the fortran function, but needs to be modified in C.

Comment: Please show the code. Especially the whole C function. See [mcve]. And how you call it in Fortran - including variable declarations. We must know where does the array originally come from.

Comment: Unless you have some other implicit typing rule in force `insv` is an integer array.  The subroutine is expecting a real argument.

Comment: Changing it to INTEGER(C_INT),DIMENSION(*) gives me the following error: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument. I also changed the C function's parameter to: int * insv

Comment: Show the **complete** code. Including `implicit none` and including all variable declarations.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, this is the complete code, there are more variables but they are all of the same, irrelevant:
    `common/bmcntc/ibmcnt(101)
      common/thropt/itopaz(101),iprm_thrm(20),rprm_thrm(20)
      common/blk03/rdumy1(2),idumy6(25),numsh12,ndtot,nsl_th,lenhsv,

     . numel2,numel4,numel6,numel8,numel10,numel20
      dimension insv(*),areas(*),xs(*),ys(*),zs(*),lsv(*),

     . ix1(*),ix2(*),ix3(*),ix4(*),aream(*),xx1(nlq,*),xx2(nlq,*)

     . ,xx3(nlq,*),stfn(*),stf(*),fni(*),dx(*),dy(*),dz(*),ua(*)`

Comment: [Edit] your question. It is impossible to read it in the comment. Start with `program`, end with `end program`. Make a full, compilable example code ([mcve]). Delete irrelevant parts of the code, but **test the reduced code** before posting it here.

Comment: And don't forget `implicit none`.

Comment: Hi vladimir, the problem is i cant post the full program since its part of a bigger program. Im just writing an extention so to say, which uses and modifies the userroutines' arrays in our C DLL logic. Also i cant use "implicit none". compiling then gives me the errors: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.

Comment: I am saying, create a program that we can test. It does not have to be *the complete code you have*, No-one wants to see thousands lines of code. We want to see **A complete compilable code** that you make by choosing the important stuff from your large code. This program MUST reproduce the problem and should be compilable by us. Have you read [mcve] already or am I just posting the link for nothing?

Comment: The subroutine as you posted it now is not legal Fortran. It will not compile. **Test the code before pasting it here!** It must be compilable and it must reproduce the problem. Reading [mcve] is essential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that:

- `insv` is an array of `real(C_DOUBLE)`
- you want to write `insv` (not to a file unit defined by `insv` as it seems now)
- the calling program defines `insv` as an array of 10 components

a possible working test case follows:

Fortran:

```
SUBROUTINE userroutine(insv)
    USE, INTRINSIC::ISO_C_BINDING
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTERFACE
        SUBROUTINE MODIFYARRAY(insv) BIND(C)
            USE, INTRINSIC::ISO_C_BINDING
            REAL(C_DOUBLE),DIMENSION(*), INTENT(INOUT) :: insv
        END SUBROUTINE MODIFYARRAY
    END INTERFACE

    real(C_DOUBLE), dimension(*) :: insv

    WRITE(*,*) insv(1)
    call modifyarray(insv)
    WRITE(*,*) insv(1)
END

PROGRAM MAIN
    USE, INTRINSIC::ISO_C_BINDING
    real(C_DOUBLE) :: insv(10)
    insv = 2.d0
    call userroutine(insv)
END
```

C:

```
void modifyarray(double * insv)
{   
    insv[0] = 1234.00;
}
```

Comment: Hello Franz, your test case has given me insight to what the problem appeared to be. In Fortran the index of an array starts at 1 whereas C starts at 0. I was changing the wrong index on the C side. Thank you very much.

Comment: On the Fortran side, not C side. At least in the incomplete code you show.